# How to find a text string within a config file and add two new lines below with one single line command?

Tags: linux, string, file, awk, config

i am trying to fight that Poodle SSL Bug and alot of configuration files have to be changed by me.

I try to save myself some work and do it by single line commands. Thus i Need to modify - for example - the /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf.

I am looking for ssl.engine = "enable"

And i want to append two new lines BELOW that found string:

```
ssl.use-sslv2          = "disable"
ssl.use-sslv3          = "disable"
```

End Result should be:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == "0.0.0.0:80" {   
ssl.engine = "enable"   
ssl.use-sslv2          = "disable"         
ssl.use-sslv3          = "disable"   
ssl.pemfile = "/etc/ssl/cert.pem"   
ssl.ca-file = "/etc/ssl/cert.bundle"   
}
```

I tried with AWK but i cant get it to work due to the spaces and the carriage return.

Happy to see some one liners :)

Here is what i tried (surely did something wrong here):

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}/ssl.engine/{a[NR+1]=a[NR+1]"ssl.use-sslv2 = "disable""}{a[NR+2]"ssl.use-sslv3 = "disable""}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print a[i]}' /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
```

Comment: could you post the contents of input file along with the exoected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print every line and if a line contains the regexp then print whatever you want:

```
awk '{print} /ssl\.engine = "enable"/{ print "ssl.use-sslv2 = \"disable\"\nssl.use-sslv3 = \"disable\"" }' file
```

Note that '.' is an RE metacharacter so it needs to be escaped in the RE context.

If you want to modify the original file then with GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace '...' file
```

and with any awk or any other UNIX tool:

```
awk '...' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Explicitly:

```
awk -i inplace '{print} /ssl\.engine = "enable"/{ print "ssl.use-sslv2 = \"disable\"\nssl.use-sslv3 = \"disable\"" }' file

awk '{print} /ssl\.engine = "enable"/{ print "ssl.use-sslv2 = \"disable\"\nssl.use-sslv3 = \"disable\"" }' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: Sorry i am relatively new to this. Can you Show me the complete single line Output to modify the file and save the changes to it ? I will better understand when i see to correct Syntax together with your Explanation above. Thanks - Stonegate

Comment: To do it with SED instead of AWK (if someone wants to know): sed 's/ssl.engine = "enable"/ssl.engine = "enable"\n   ssl.use-sslv2 = "disable"\n   ssl.use-sslv3 = "disable"/' /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf > tmp.file && mv -f tmp.file /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

How about `sed`?

```
sed 's/ssl.engine = "enable"/ssl.engine = "enable"\nssl.use-sslv2 = "disable"\nssl.use-sslv3 = "disable"/' config
```

Use `sed -i` to substitute in-place:

```
sed -i 's/ssl.engine = "enable"/ssl.engine = "enable"\nssl.use-sslv2 = "disable"\nssl.use-sslv3 = "disable"/' config
```

Comment: Cool that works. I improved it a bit by formating and you had a typo (sue instead of use).. However it is not writing the changes to the config file but just Displays the correct Change to the Output. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: sed 's/ssl.engine = "enable"/ssl.engine = "enable"\n   ssl.use-sslv2 = "disable"\n   ssl.use-sslv3 = "disable"/' /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf

Comment: Strange Thing is it does not save the changes to /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf - it is just displaying the new Output on Screen but when i vi /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf and look into that particular section i just find the old Content without that modification

Comment: Not all seds support `-i` and not all seds support using `\n` instead of a backslash followed by a literal newline. Maybe either or both of those are the issue. You can always do `sed '...' file > tmp && mv tmp file` just like with any UNIX command.

Comment: i tried a bit and this works for me: sed 's/ssl.engine = "enable"/ssl.engine = "enable"\n   ssl.use-sslv2 = "disable"\n   ssl.use-sslv3 = "disable"/' /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf > tmp.file && mv -f tmp.file /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf